# How to pass two anonymous functions as arguments in CoffeScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, anonymous-function, coffeescript

I want to pass two anonymous functions as arguments for jQuery's hover, like so:

```
$('element').hover(
  function() {
    // do stuff on mouseover
  },
  function() {
    // do stuff on mouseout
  }
);
```

It's easy with just one – `hover ->` – but what is the proper syntax in CoffeeScript for two? I tried `...hover ->`, `...hover( ->...`, etc. but nothing gets me the above structure.

Comment: name your anonymous functions. do it right now. you don't have proper names, so call them `f` and `g`: `f = (...) -> ...`, `g = ...`. then `( $ 'element' ).hover f, g`. so simple, so expressive.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Put parentheses around the anonymous functions.

Comment: I swear I did this - what I was alluding to with hover( -> - but just did it again andit worked. Thanks!

Comment: It should be noted though, that there has be exactly zero whitespace between hover and the parantheses.
$(@).hover() != $(@).hover ()
Otherwise, the output would be wrapped in another set of parantheses.

Comment: Not enough info in this answer, Anurag's answer better explains what to do.

Answer (score 52):

I think the problem lies with using single line comments `//`. Single-line comments enclosed in `/* .. */` seem to work fine. Here's an equivalent example with something other than a comment.

```
$('element').hover(
  -> console.log("first")
  -> console.log("second")
)
```

Or with comments using `/* .. */`.

```
$('element').hover(
  -> /* first */
  -> /* second */
)
```

You can try these examples under the [Try CoffeeScript](http://jashkenas.github.com/coffee-script/) tab. CoffeeScript adds a return statement to return the last expression of the function. If you wanted bare-bones functions which do nothing and don't contain a `return` at the end, try:

```
$('element').hover(
  () ->
  () ->
)
// $('element').hover(function() {}, function() {});
```

Comment: If anybody stumbled upon this: careful not to insert a space here: `hover (`, you will end up with extra parentheses.

Answer (score 21):

Another way is to use **backslash** after the caller function, the comma should be indented correctly.

```
$('element').hover \
  -> # do stuff on mouseover
  ,
  -> # do stuff on mouseout
```

Comment: Thanks, \ is very good to go. while in long lines of code, we don't need to search and find ). Using \ with , is really simple. I feel jquery while using () again.

Answer (score 8):

**Without parenthesis or backslash**:

```
f ->
  0
, ->
  1
```

Output on 1.7.1:

```
f(function() {
  return 0;
}, function() {
  return 1;
});
```