# Multiple Functions as Arguments in CoffeeScript

Tags: jquery, syntax, coffeescript

I can't for the life of me figure this out or find a solution online.  I am trying to figure out how to write a script in CoffeeScript from jQuery based JavaScript.

The script is this:

```
jQuery('.post-thumb a').hover( function() {
    jQuery(this).find('.overlay').fadeIn(150);
}, function() {
    jQuery(this).find('.overlay').fadeOut(150);
});
```

I initially tried rewriting that like this:

```
thumb_overlay =>
    $('.post-thumb a').hover
        => $(this).find('.overlay').fadeIn(150)
        ,=> $(this).find('.overlay').fadeOut(150)
```

But that didn't work, so I thought I would post here.  So how do I write that JavaScript in CoffeeScript?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/6463052/66226

Comment: My apologies Tever.  I didn't know that those were anonymous functions and thus I couldn't find anything with searches.

Comment: http://js2coffee.org/

Answer (score 69, accepted):

I think you're almost there but you need some parentheses (to group things) and some backslashes to keep CoffeeScript from misinterpreting the newlines. Try this:

```
thumb_overlay =>
    $('.post-thumb a').hover \
        (=> $(this).find('.overlay').fadeIn(150)), \
        (=> $(this).find('.overlay').fadeOut(150))
```

You could also mash it all into one line but you might regret it in a few months:

```
thumb_overlay =>
    $('.post-thumb a').hover (=> $(this).find('.overlay').fadeIn(150)), (=> $(this).find('.overlay').fadeOut(150))
```

And BTW, go to the [homepage](https://coffeescript.org) and hit "Try CoffeeScript", that's an easy way to sort small bits of CoffeeScript out; start with the `->` version to cut down on the noise in the JavaScript and then switch to `=>` when you get the right JavaScript.

I'm not sure if you want to `=>` forms in this case, the `->` form form:

```
$('.post-thumb a').hover \
    (-> $(this).find('.overlay').fadeIn(150)), \
    (-> $(this).find('.overlay').fadeOut(150))
```

would give you the the JavaScript that you started with:

```
$('.post-thumb a').hover((function() {
  return $(this).find('.overlay').fadeIn(150);
}), (function() {
  return $(this).find('.overlay').fadeOut(150);
}));
```

And if you don't like backslashes, you could do this:

```
$('.post-thumb a').hover( 
    -> $(this).find('.overlay').fadeIn(150)
    -> $(this).find('.overlay').fadeOut(150)
)
```

Or if your functions are longer, you could give them names and skip a lot of the problem:

```
fadeIn  = -> $(this).find('.overlay').fadeIn(150)
fadeOut = -> $(this).find('.overlay').fadeOut(150)
$('.post-thumb a').hover(fadeIn, fadeOut)
```

I tend to prefer this approach in both JavaScript and CoffeeScript, reads better to me.

Comment: The second backslash is unnecessary. The first is only necessary because you're omitting parentheses and the CoffeeScript parser will assume that the line is a complete function call unless you explicitly include a backslash to indicate the line continues. If you parenthesized, you wouldn't need any backslashes.

Comment: @Chuck: We can call that personal preference. I actually like parentheses so I'd use them (and ignore the dirty looks) but a lot of people seem not to like them. I'd probably go with my (updated) last version in Real Life but I don't do that much CoffeeScript so I'm still fumbling around a bit.

Comment: I had been trying to do the Try CoffeeScript to make sure it worked, but nothing would compile beyond the hover method (none of the arguments), so I new I had something wrong.  Is there a way to load the interactive console with jQuery to test there?

Comment: @Dave: Not that I know of. You might be able to make something go with jsfiddle and http://jsfiddle.net/kaleb/neEp4/ though.

Comment: I actually found a Coda plugin that lets me compile and test coffeescript with jQuery

Comment: In your last example, the second comma is not needed either.

Comment: @skizeey: True enough, thanks. I've done a bit more CoffeeScript since this answer, these days I'd probably go with this structure just to avoid having to worry about the whitespace: `a = -> ...; b = -> ...; $(x).hover(a, b)` (with better names of course).

Comment: @mu is too short: sorry, I meant the first comma, but I guess you understood what I meant. Regarding your solution: it would definitely work a lot of the times. But bear in mind, though, that CoffeeScript uses [implicit scoping](http://lucumr.pocoo.org/2011/12/22/implicit-scoping-in-coffeescript/) and so initializing those functions could over-write a variable that you declared of the same name, in an upper scope. But that's just a precaution.

Comment: @skizeey: But if you're having that sort of scoping problem then your code is probably a hopeless incomprehensible mess.

Comment: I prefer this form

    $('.post-thumb a').hover( 
        -> $(this).find('.overlay').fadeIn(150)
        -> $(this).find('.overlay').fadeOut(150)
    )

Answer (score 25):

For those searching for an answer in 2014 CoffeeScript,

```
$('someSelector').hover ->
  alert "hello"
, ->
  alert "world"
```

compiles into

```
$('someSelector').hover(function() {
  return alert("hello");
}, function() {
  return alert("world");
});
```