# jquery.delegate() and Coffeescript

Tags: jquery, coffeescript

I am a newbie in Coffeescript and would like to use the delegate() method in jquery 1.6.4. The method signature is `.delegate( selector, eventType, handler )`. How do I go about calling this method in Coffeescript? I am using Rails 3.1.

Thanks,
Dany.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

just like any other method in coffeescript?

```
($ 'body').delegate '.external.link', 'click', (evt) ->
  # handler body
```

i feel like i'm missing something about your question...

Comment: Many thanks, it seems amazingly obvious now that you've said it. However, what happens if there are two handlers in the parameters?

Comment: isn't the $sign on the wrong side of the parenthesis?

Comment: @bobbdelsol: no.  `$ 'body'` is a coffeescript expressioon just like `$('body')` in javascript. `$ 'body'.delegate` in cs is *unlike* `$('body').delegate` in js, and parentheses reset operator precedence in both languages.  `($ 'body').delegate` in cs is just like `($('body')).delegate` in js.

Answer (score 3):

To reply to your 2 handlers question:

```
$('body').hover ->
  # handler 1
  console.log 'in'
, ->
  # handler 2
  console.log 'out'
```

http://js2coffee.org/ is a good website to have in background if you write coffeescript without an automatic compiler that allows you to check imediatly the resulting javascript.

Comment: Or alternatively, you can wrap each handler in parentheses. This question comes up a lot... see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6463052/how-to-pass-two-anonymous-functions-as-arguments-in-coffescript.

Comment: Yes it's sometimes the easiest way

Comment: Thank you - I use Textmate with Coffeescript bundle so I can compile and check.

Answer (score 1):

It's a pure matter of aesthetics, but I prefer to wrap my handlers in named functions (if there's more than one):

```
    over = => ...
    out  = => ...

    $el.hover over, out
```

It just seems cleaner for me.

Answer (score 1):

I may be dense but the correct answer above took me some time to figure out.
the first parameter is the div or ? that you want to watch for new elements, then you need to provide the element identifier , then the event type

```
$('#forum-senate-admin-lists').delegate 'input[id=delete-forum-object]','click', (evt) ->
    deleteForumObject($(this))`
```